# Проблема с кодировкой php mail()

Tags: php, phpmailer

Почитал статьи по поводу этой функции и это ошибки. Везде разное решение. Хотелось бы понять, какое верное со стороны разработки.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['email'])) {$email = $_POST['email']; if ($email == '') {unset($email);}}
if (isset($_POST['phone'])) {$phone = $_POST['phone']; if ($phone == '') {$phone = 'Не оставлен';}}
if (isset($_POST['text'])) {$text = $_POST['text']; if ($text == '') {unset($text);}}
 
if (isset($email) && isset($text)){


$to      = 'whisper@***ects.ru';
$subject = 'New order from your website ***ects.ru!';
$message = 'Телефон:'.$phone."\n".'Почта:'.$email."\n".'Сообщение:'.$text;
$headers = array(
    'From' => 'whisper@***ects.ru',
    'Reply-To' => '***@mail.ru',
    'X-Mailer' => 'PHP/' . phpversion()
);

$send = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);


if ($send == 'true') {
 $response = [
    'ok'=>'success'
 ];
}
else {
 $response = [
    'ok'=>'error!'
 ];
}}
 
echo json_encode($response);

?>
```

Как видите, стоит пересылка на ***@mail.ru и как раз туда приходит все в нормальном текстовом виде, а в roundcube приходит

```
New order from your website ***ects.ru!

  Ð¢ÐµÐ»ÐµÑ„Ð¾Ð½:
  ÐŸÐ¾Ñ‡Ñ‚Ð°:***@inbox.ru
  Ð¡Ð¾Ð¾Ð±Ñ‰ÐµÐ½Ð¸Ðµ:Ð¿Ñ€Ð¾Ð³ÑƒÐ»Ð¾Ðº
```

**Как исправить неверную кодировку?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В $hearders добавьте следущий код,если используется utf-8 то вместо `Windows-1251` вставьте свою кодировку
Вот код:
`"Content-type: text/html; charset=Windows-1251\r\n";`

Comment: Я изменил строку и сделал такую `'X-Mailer' => "Content-type: text/html; charset=Windows-1251\r\n".'PHP/' . phpversion()`, однако ничего не поменялось

Comment: Добавь кодировку ```utf-8```